# Beta coefficients vs. Model Comparisons in LME models

Tags: r, lme4-nlme

I have run three non-hierarchical LME models testing how certain variables predict ratings.

```
self  <- lmer(rating ~ own_pref + (1|subject) + (1|image), REML = FALSE, data=td_pref1)
summary(self)

kid <- lmer(rating ~ mean_p2 + (1|subject) + (1|image), REML = FALSE, data=td_pref1)
summary(kid)

adu <- lmer(rating ~ mean_p1 + (1|subject) + (1|image), REML = FALSE, data=td_pref1)
summary(adu)
```

Looking at the results of the models, mean_p2 appears to have the largest beta-coefficient and; therefore, I interpret this as suggesting that the mean_p2 is most predictive of ratings.

Here are the results of self:

```
Linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood . t-tests use Satterthwaite's method ['lmerModLmerTest']
Formula: rating ~ own_pref + (1 | subject) + (1 | image)
   Data: td_pref1

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
 32249.6  32286.4 -16119.8  32239.6    11573 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-4.2186 -0.6418  0.0633  0.6714  3.2811 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 image    (Intercept) 0.10981  0.3314  
 subject  (Intercept) 0.06416  0.2533  
 Residual             0.90625  0.9520  
Number of obs: 11578, groups:  image, 120; subject, 98

Fixed effects:
                Estimate   Std. Error           df t value            Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)     3.331125     0.050133   440.549038   66.45 <0.0000000000000002 ***
own_pref        0.094657     0.007638 11450.525191   12.39 <0.0000000000000002 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
         (Intr)
own_pref -0.587
```

kid:

```
Linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood . t-tests use Satterthwaite's method ['lmerModLmerTest']
Formula: rating ~ mean_p2 + (1 | subject) + (1 | image)
   Data: td_pref1

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
 32364.2  32400.9 -16177.1  32354.2    11573 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-4.2925 -0.6359  0.0677  0.6702  3.1826 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 image    (Intercept) 0.08948  0.2991  
 subject  (Intercept) 0.07032  0.2652  
 Residual             0.91658  0.9574  
Number of obs: 11578, groups:  image, 120; subject, 98

Fixed effects:
             Estimate Std. Error        df t value            Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   2.16339    0.23611 122.89764   9.163 0.00000000000000142 ***
mean_p2       0.40711    0.06186 119.78332   6.581 0.00000000129305539 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
        (Intr)
mean_p2 -0.986
```

and adu:

```
Linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood . t-tests use Satterthwaite's method ['lmerModLmerTest']
Formula: rating ~ mean_p1 + (1 | subject) + (1 | image)
   Data: td_pref1

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
 32363.1  32399.9 -16176.6  32353.1    11573 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-4.2856 -0.6361  0.0671  0.6712  3.1891 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 image    (Intercept) 0.08864  0.2977  
 subject  (Intercept) 0.07031  0.2652  
 Residual             0.91658  0.9574  
Number of obs: 11578, groups:  image, 120; subject, 98

Fixed effects:
             Estimate Std. Error        df t value             Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   2.29218    0.21354 123.58887  10.734 < 0.0000000000000002 ***
mean_p1       0.36197    0.05414 119.77567   6.686        0.00000000077 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
        (Intr)
mean_p1 -0.983
```

That said when I compare these three models with the `ANOVA` function in R, self has the lowest BIC value suggesting, qualitatively, that the model with self as a predictor of ratings offers a better fit than the other two models. I'm confused as to how the beta coefficients are telling a different story than the BIC values.

```
Models:
self: rating ~ own_pref + (1 | subject) + (1 | image)
kid: rating ~ mean_p2 + (1 | subject) + (1 | image)
adu: rating ~ mean_p1 + (1 | subject) + (1 | image)
     npar   AIC   BIC logLik deviance  Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)
self    5 32250 32286 -16120    32240                     
kid     5 32364 32401 -16177    32354 0.0000  0           
adu     5 32363 32400 -16177    32353 1.0138  0
```

---

edit: So as mentioned in the comments own_pref is a categorical 1-6 Likert variable and mean_p1/2 are both means so continuous in nature. I am now starting to wonder if own_pref has a lower BIC simply because the categorical nature of the predictor reduces complexity. Could this be what's happening?

Comment: Are the three predictors (own_pref, mean_p1 and mean_p2) on the same scale? This matters since if you divide the predictor by 2 then the beta coefficient will be multiplied by 2.

Comment: Asside from comparing coefficients not being very meaningful, the model comparisons via deviance may be bad as well. This is because the assumptions of the distribution are not the same as you are refitting the covariance matrix. Comparing likelihoods can be tricky (e.g. think of Bernoulli versus binomial modelling the same data but with different scale factors for the likelihood).